# I didn't understand why both an implicit and an explicit nonce is used in AES-GCM in TLS 1.2

Tags: aes, tls, nonce

As per my understanding that the nonce of AES-GCM in SSL has 3 parts:

.  salt, 4 bytes, generated in handshake, not changed in whole session
.  nonce_explicit, 8 bytes, chosen by the sender and carried in each SSL record
.  inner_counter, 4 bytes, used in AES-GCM internal

Question: I am not understanding that, what is main purpose of using these implicit nonce and explicit nonce and why it is only sending explicit part only?what happens if we not use implicit part of nonce?

Can anyone please give me some understanding over it.

Answer (score 6):

> Question: I am not understanding that, what is main purpose of using these implicit nonce and explicit nonce and why it is only sending explicit part only?

With the nonce, one important goal we need to ensure is that we never encrypt two different records with the same nonce.  By having an 8 byte nonce in the record (and ensuring that two different record-nonces will always translate to two different GCM nonces), we can encrypt $2^{64}$ records and still abide by this limit (and we probably don't want to go beyond that anyways; the security proofs tend to break down if we get close to the 'birthday bound').

That said, why do we have the 'implicit nonce' (aka the salt)?  Well, that's there to frustrate a multitarget attack.

Suppose an attacker were able to collect a huge number of TLS connections; assume also that each connection has a record with a common record-nonce (because the RFC places no restrictions on how record-nonces are generated, this is plausible).  Assume that the attacker's goal is to decrypt one of those sessions (and he doesn't care which one it is).  Then, what the attacker can do is guess a key, and then do a parallel check on that record from each connection simultaneously (which is a lot more efficient than trying to decrypt each record in succession); if the attacker has collected $2^k$ connections and each connection has a 128 bit key, this reduces the security to $128-k$.

Now, this attack requires that the GCM nonces be exactly identical; by including the salt in the GCM-nonce, the increases the work effort of this attack from $2^{128-k}$ to $2^{128+32-k}$.  What that means is that, unless the attacker has $k > 32$ (that is, he has more than 4 billions captured sessions), then this attacker takes more work then the simple 'pick a connection, brute force attack that one' attack (which the secret salt does not frustrate if we assume the attacker has some known plaintext).

Now, having the salt secret doesn't actually make anything more secure (against either attack); however there's also no specific reason to expose it, and so they don't.

Comment: Thank you so much for you answer. And I did'nt got the point why explicit nonce is sending and what is the use of it? and why implicit nonce is maintained in the handshake process itself?

Comment: @prasad: the explicit nonce is there because we need the nonce that we give to GCM to be different every time, and the sender can ensure it.  An alternative design would be make the current record counter this 'explicit nonce', and not send it at all - I don't know why they didn't go with this alternative design.  As for the implicit nonce, as I stated, it's there to frustrate multitarget attacks, and deriving it from the handshake process is one good way to do it.

Comment: Thank you, Now i got some understanding. Can you please provide how the implementation of these AES-GCM flow like small pseudo code, I am very new to these.if you don't mine. Means how the IV ,additional data ,plain text and key as taken for encryption what is the steps required for this?